# Getting Blood Glucose from HealthKit Query

Tags: swift, healthkit

I am trying to pull blood glucose values from a query I have made to get the last 10 in the Health App. I am able to pull the data from the Health app and get it in the form for a single entry:

```
(2017-02-21 13:13:00 -0500 - 2017-02-21 13:13:00 -0500), 80 mg/dL 52D7A973-7853-455C-9308-0E339153A3BE "Health" (10.2.1) metadata: {
HKWasUserEntered = 1;}
```

I am able to pull the startdate (and endDate) from this by adding:

```
guard let timing = reading?.endDate as Date? else {
                print("timing scheme didn't work.")
                return
            }

print(timing)
```

and pull the type (HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodGlucose) by writing

```
guard let bg = reading?.sampleType as HKSampleType? else {
                print("bg scheme didn't work")
                return
            }

print(bg)
```

However, I can not figure out to print the actual blood glucose value (ie. 80 mg/dL).

I tried:

```
let bg = reading.quantity
```

but I got the error

```
Value of type 'Optional<HKSample>' has no member 'quantity'
```

If anyone has insight to this, it would be extremely helpful! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
// To read blood glucose:
            let gluco = reading as? HKQuantitySample
            if let bg = gluco?.quantity {
                print(bg)
            }
```